# Error message: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=+justification]

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

The code:

```
$('option[value=+justification]').attr('selected',true);
```

Error Message:

> Error message: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   [value=+justification]

How to escape `+` or `-` sign?

**Note: I tried also this:**

```
$('option[value=\+justification]').attr('selected',true);
```

But still same error.

**HTML:**

```
<select class="reason" name="reason">
<option value="-justification">-justification</option>
<option value="+justification">+justification</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried $('option[value="+justification"]').attr('selected',true);

Comment: @NigelEllis: I will and let you know

Comment: @NigelEllis: yes it works fine with double quotes